# Vue Jest Pass Data to Component

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, nuxt.js

new to testing and was wondering if there was another way to inject data back to the component other than what's on the docs

**The Docs**

```
const Component = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <span id="foo">{{ foo }}</span>
      <span id="bar">{{ bar }}</span>
    </div>
  `,

  data() {
    return {
      foo: 'foo',
      bar: 'bar'
    }
  }
}

const wrapper = mount(Component, {
  data() {
    return {
      bar: 'my-override'
    }
  }
})

wrapper.find('#foo').text() // 'foo'
wrapper.find('#bar').text() // 'my-override'
```

It seems like the relevant parts of the component are copied (mocked?) into the test itself and the test + data are self-containing. Is there a way to send the data back into the component and test what's there?

Ideally I want to be able to tweak the value of a variable from the test, and then have that pass to the component to display the correct card.

**Something like:**

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div v-if="cardOne" id="card1">Text 1</div>

    <div v-if="cardTwo" id="card2">Text 2</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    //loop to go through numberArray
    // if x = 1, this.cardOne = true and card1 is shown
    // if x=2, this.cardTwo = true and card2 is shown etc

    //Can I manually set x = 1 from the test, and then see if cardOne renders on the component?
  },
  data() {
    return {
      numberArray: [1, 2],
      cardOne: false,
      cardTwo: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your component gets data via props you can use [props](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#props) (Vue 3) or [propsData](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#propsdata) (Vue 2) property of `options` object to pass data to it when you call `shallowMount`/`mount`.

If your component has some default values after instantiation and you want to change them your way is correct. You pass data via `data` method and if you want to change these values  later in the test you should use [setData](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setdata) method of your `wrapper` instance as it's shown in docs. API of this method is the same for both Vue 2 and Vue 3 apps.

Comment: Ah gotcha, just got the setData method working. Thanks!